# Некорректная кодировка данных отправленных методом POST

Tags: node.js, html

Есть форма отправки сообщения.

```
<form action="/upload" method="post">
 <textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit text">
</form>
```

И есть код, который обрабатывает это сообщение

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var postData = '';
  req.setEncoding('utf8');

  req.addListener('data', function(postDataChunk) {
    postData += postDataChunk;
    console.log('Новые данные: ' + postDataChunk);
  });
  req.addListener('end', function() {
   res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
   res.write("Вы загрузили:" + postData);
   res.end();
  });
}).listen(1337,'127.0.0.1');
```

Сообщение принимает, но выводит в неправильной кодировке (кириллицу) в виде всяких разных крякозябр. Кодировка страницы UTF-8 (без BOM). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы символы кириллицы корректно выводились?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все элементарно, у вас не указана кодировка ни в ответе сервера, ни в заголовке страницы. Кодировка по умолчанию cp1251, вот и получаете *"кракозябры"*, с т.з. node.js лечиться так:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
});
```

---

Дело в том, что браузер, перед отправкой данных формы, использует URI кодирование строки, в общем добавьте в обработчик `request.on('end')` разбор пришедших данных:

```
req.addListener('end', function() {
  var post = require('querystring').parse( postData )
  // querystring - нативный модуль node.js
  route(handle, pathname, res, post);
});
```

Теперь переменная post - это JS объект, в котором хранятся полученные данные, в вашем случае - **post.text**, т.е. все будет приведено к примерно такой-же схеме как и в PHP. В общем - измените еще

```
 res.write("Вы загрузили:" + postData);
```

на

```
 res.write("Вы загрузили:" + postData.text);
```

и будет вам счастье =)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с тем, что в браузере возвращаются крякозяблики вместо кириллицы. 
cmd
chcp 866 - проверял

iconv.decode
не спасает.
Например:

```
1
exec("dir /D", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
2
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
3
        var convert=iconv.decode(stdout, "CP866");
4
        response.write(convert);
5
        response.end();
6
    });
7
}
```